# How do I use my Samsung Gear Circle bluetooth headset with Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, drivers, bluetooth

I recently purchased the [Samsung Gear Circle](http://www.samsung.com/global/microsite/gearcircle/) with the intention of using it both with my Android phone and my PC. It works wonderfully with my phone. I like the sound, fit, look, and features. However, I also need it to work with my laptop, as I want to use it to make calls through my Cisco softphone and Google Hangouts, and also to listen to music.

I talked to Samsung tech support, and was told that this bluetooth headset is not supported for Windows 7. I am able to get it to pair, and it shows up in the Sound panel, but it is greyed out. I right-click on it, and click connect, but nothing happens.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled my USB bluetooth adapter (Broadcom 3.0), and I have also updated the [driver](https://www.broadcom.com/support/bluetooth/update.php) for the adapter, but I still cannot get it to work properly with Windows 7.

Does anyone have any suggestions for me?

Comment: Based on what you describe the headset does support Windows 7.